# Получение Json с сайта

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-apps-script

Как получить Json не логинясь на сайт?
Если есть куки при переходе по ссылке сайт выплевывает JSON
https://www.fastgraphs.com/cgi-bin/data.xfds.pl?ticker=NYS:MCD&epscode=fcflps

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке зайти без них сайт выдает пустой массив {} Можно ли дописать что то в адресную строку чтобы он выдал ответ как с cookie?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете как получать данные без **авторизации** на их сайте? Ваш скриншот сделан из под demo-учетки?

Comment: Да, учетка демо, разницы между демо и обычной нет. Не совсем без авторизации, спрашиваю можно ли через оператор & дописать что то из куков в строку браузера чтобы получить ответ от сервера как авторизованному.

Comment: Скорее всего, там сессии открывают доступ для `JSON`, после авторизации. Получить это без авторизации не получится. И ничего вы там не пропишите в адресную строку.

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю как такое реализовать с помощью PHP CURL

1) если у Вас есть файл cookie готовый и он не требует модификации то это легко

2) если файл куки требует модификации то это уже гимморой !!! но всё ещё возможен для PHP CURL

Для первого варианта))

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'Адрес страницы');    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'Полный путь к вашему cookie файлу');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'Полный путь к вашему cookie файлу');
    // Тут косим под браузер ( изучив заголовки отправления )
    $header = array();
    $header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,* /*;q=0.8";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "DNT: 1";
    $header[] = "Host: Хост хозяина к которому идём"; // ВАЖНО
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    // Пишем типа наш браузер
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

    // Пишем с какой страницы пришли !!! Бывает важно если ведётся статистика которая всё нам обломает ( идеально чтоб рефферер был правдивый )
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http:// с какой страницы я делаю запрос');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    // Пофигу HTTP это или HTTPS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

    // совершаем HTTP запрос и получаем содержимое ответа в переменную $con ... дальше парсим её и сами формируем данные как нам угодно.
    $con = curl_exec($ch);

    // закрываем соединение
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Для варианта 2 и далее нужно изучать логику и писать бота!
Основу я Вам предоставил